# Open a already created form from main form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have two windows form main and other which I add in my project. Second forms have some content `buttons, rich text boxes, label` and e.t.c. I want to open the second window, from main form using button click, I using this code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exam frm= new Exam();
            frm.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Than program pops out a new window, but no content, which I have already added in second window. PLEASE HELP SOMEONE :)

This is `Exam.Designer.cs` file:

```
namespace Legal_Hunt {
    partial class Exam
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.richTextBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;
            this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 8);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 173);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 188);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 269);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 350);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button3.Text = "button3";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this.button4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 431);
            this.button4.Name = "button4";
            this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button4.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button4.Text = "button4";
            this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // richTextBox2
            // 
            this.richTextBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 8);
            this.richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2";
            this.richTextBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 173);
            this.richTextBox2.TabIndex = 5;
            this.richTextBox2.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox3
            // 
            this.richTextBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(631, 188);
            this.richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3";
            this.richTextBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.richTextBox3.TabIndex = 6;
            this.richTextBox3.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox4
            // 
            this.richTextBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(631, 269);
            this.richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4";
            this.richTextBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.richTextBox4.TabIndex = 7;
            this.richTextBox4.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox5
            // 
            this.richTextBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 350);
            this.richTextBox5.Name = "richTextBox5";
            this.richTextBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 75);
            this.richTextBox5.TabIndex = 8;
            this.richTextBox5.Text = "";
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this.button5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 431);
            this.button5.Name = "button5";
            this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.button5.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button5.Text = "დაწყება";
            this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
            // 
            // Exam
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(812, 538);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(828, 577);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(828, 577);
            this.Name = "Exam";
            this.Text = "Exam";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button5;
    } }
```

and this is `Exam.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace Legal_Hunt
{
    public partial class Exam : Form
    {

        public Exam()
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button5.Text = "მომდევნო";


        }
    }
```

In this case Second form is blank when pops out
but when i change `Exam.cs` file like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace Legal_Hunt
{
    public partial class Exam : Form
    {

        public Exam()
        {
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.richTextBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.richTextBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Salmon;
            this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 8);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 173);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 188);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 269);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 350);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button3.Text = "button3";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this.button4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 431);
            this.button4.Name = "button4";
            this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 75);
            this.button4.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button4.Text = "button4";
            this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // richTextBox2
            // 
            this.richTextBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 8);
            this.richTextBox2.Name = "richTextBox2";
            this.richTextBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 173);
            this.richTextBox2.TabIndex = 5;
            this.richTextBox2.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox3
            // 
            this.richTextBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(631, 188);
            this.richTextBox3.Name = "richTextBox3";
            this.richTextBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.richTextBox3.TabIndex = 6;
            this.richTextBox3.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox4
            // 
            this.richTextBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(631, 269);
            this.richTextBox4.Name = "richTextBox4";
            this.richTextBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.richTextBox4.TabIndex = 7;
            this.richTextBox4.Text = "";
            // 
            // richTextBox5
            // 
            this.richTextBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 350);
            this.richTextBox5.Name = "richTextBox5";
            this.richTextBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 75);
            this.richTextBox5.TabIndex = 8;
            this.richTextBox5.Text = "";
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this.button5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Sylfaen", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(630, 431);
            this.button5.Name = "button5";
            this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 75);
            this.button5.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button5.Text = "დაწყება";
            this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
            // 
            // Exam
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(812, 538);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(828, 577);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(828, 577);
            this.Name = "Exam";
            this.Text = "Exam";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button5.Text = "მომდევნო";


        }
    }
}
```

everything is OK. Should it be like this?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Can you explain a little better?

Comment: this click event handler creates a new instance of the `Exam` form. Unless you fill its controls with content in its constructor or some pre-show event handler, it will always be blank. So what do you mean with "... content, which I have already added ..."?

Comment: Exam form has content but when pops out don't have.

Comment: Maybe show us more code? Relevant parts of the rest of the code?

Comment: Are you sure the controls are initializing from the constructor of Exam class?

Comment: Well you can't show another window from MainWindow until Exam closes due to it being a modal dialog for one

Comment: is it A) the controls are visible on the form designer, at design time, but missing at runtime => could be that `InitializeComponent` is missing/never called, in this case debug and fix; or B) the *content* of the controls, meaning text, captions on buttons, ... are blank?

Comment: There is just blank window no texts buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the method InitializeComponent() in your constructor.

```
public Exam()
 {
   InitializeComponent() 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ShowDialog, try just using .Show();

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exam frm= new Exam();
        // frm.ShowDialog();

        frm.Show();
    }
```